# Should we let Python pip overwrite modules that were installed by RPM?

Tags: centos, python, pip

Python `pip` and many Python modules are provided through the CentOS Linux repos. On CentOS 7.x Linux, I can install `pip` and `pymongo` with the standard distribution package manager (`yum install python-pip python-pymongo`).

However, the version of `pymongo` which is available from the repo is already too old. The version of `pip` is usually behind, too, so it immediately recommends running `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Is there a consensus on what one should do here? Using `pip` to run updates will be overwriting files that came from the RPMs, so you're likely to get complaints about that from the package manager.

Is it better not to install `pip` and the modules from RPM? Perhaps just installing Python from RPM and then installing all modules from `pip` (so that none of the Python modules are from RPM and are wholly managed by `pip`)?

Comment: IMO it is **always** best to stay within the packaging system.  Sometimes this will mean building your own package of an updated (or unpackaged) program or library or module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question.  It talks about having pip install in a different directory.  This would allow you to maintain the rpm installs and have the latest version.  I would probably uninstall the rpm version if you don't plan to use it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to use python just for yourself without messing up your system's python,  take a look at a product called Anaconda from Continuum. [http://Continuum.io/downloads](http://Continuum.io/downloads%20get%20Anaconda%20here)  this  install of python etc...  will install in your home directory and change paths so you're not installing to your systems python and possibly messing up your system.  You can also make virtual environments and Conda environments of these options allow  you to try something out and if you don't like it just blow away the environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it better not to install pip and the modules from RPM? Perhaps just
>   installing Python from RPM and then installing all modules from pip
>   (so that none of the Python modules are from RPM and are wholly
>   managed by pip)?

It is 'ok' to install pip and other Python modules from your OS's package manager. You may no longer have a choice about it since a lot of system components depend on Python and even in a minimal install version of the OS, you will find Python + Python modules installed as default.

So whenever you feel that you need to upgrade the 'system-wide' version of pip or any of the Python modules, but don't want to interfere with the files managed by the package manager, you should do the following:

The following instructions are for a RHEL derivative OS and the Python version available at the time was 2.7.x. You will need to adjust the PYTHONPATH to match your installed version of Python.

- Ensure that the package manager version of python-pip is installed. e.g. `yum -y install python-pip`.
- Create a profile.d script to set up the PYTHONPATH environment variable:

  ```
  # Ensure PYTHONPATH is configured to use /usr/local/lib*/python2.7/site-packages
  read -r -d '' pythonpath_profile_script <<'EOF'
  pythonpathmunge () {
      case ":${PYTHONPATH}:" in
          *:"$1":*)
              ;;
          *)
              if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                  PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$1
              else
                  PYTHONPATH=$1:$PYTHONPATH
              fi
      esac
  }

  pythonpathmunge /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  pythonpathmunge /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
  export PYTHONPATH
  EOF

  echo "Creating the /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh profile script:"
  echo "${pythonpath_profile_script}" > /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh
  chown root.root /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh
  chmod -v 0644 /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh
  source /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh
  hash -r
  ```
- You can then choose to install the latest version of pip or any other python-module via:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade <<PYTHON MODULE NAME>> --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local" --log /var/log/<<PYTHON MODULE NAME>>-install-$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log
  ```

  e.g.

  ```
  pip install --upgrade pip --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local" --log /var/log/pip-install-$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log
  hash -r
  # Notice the use of `hash -r` to refresh bash's hash table of recently
  # executable programs. Without doing this you may find that the 'pip'
  # command being used is not the version you just installed.
  ```

This will install the requested Python module under `/usr/local` where it won't interfere with the files managed by the system package manager. The `--ignore-installed` option ensures pip doesn't touch the existing version of the module. Also, due to the use of the PYTHONPATH environment variable, the `/usr/local/lib*/python2.7/site-packages` paths will be used before any system installed packages. i.e.

```
[root@localhost ~]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages        <---
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages          <---
/root
/usr/lib64/python27.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>>>
```

Lastly, at least on CentOS/RHEL, the `/usr/local/bin` path is before any of the other system binary paths in the PATH environment variable and hence this also ensures that any newer binaries installed in /usr/local/bin take precendence above system installed ones. i.e.

```
[root@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

[CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) 7.x is derived from Red Hat Enterprise 7.x, which is designed to be *stable*.  That inevitably means that the programs which are available from the repositories have been tested for a while.  You can see that from the description on their website:

> The CentOS Project is a community-driven free software effort focused on delivering a ***robust*** open source ecosystem. For users, we offer a ***consistent manageable platform*** that suits a wide variety of deployments. For open source communities, we offer a ***solid, predictable base*** to build upon, along with extensive resources to build, test, release, and maintain their code.

If you want "bleeding-edge" code, you can use [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Project_Wiki).  Fedora has different goals:

> The Fedora Project is a global partnership of free software community members. The Fedora Project is sponsored by Red Hat, which invests in our infrastructure and resources to encourage collaboration and ***incubate innovative new technologies***. **Some** of these technologies may later be integrated into Red Hat products. They are developed in Fedora and produced under a free and open source license from inception, so other free software communities and projects are free to study, adopt, and modify them.

There are of course tradeoffs, but you cannot have both "stable" and "new" at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. You are correct in your summary of CentOS. It is true that new cannot be guaranteed to be stable. Nevertheless, we have many users that want newer packages on CentOS systems. We are forced to offer newer versions as an option, but will follow other advice here (which is to stick within the packaging system and offer newer versions via alternate directory paths).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a consensus on what one should do here?

Yes, do not modify system-managed Python installation manually (running pip) – see [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735) For in depth discussion of the subject please read pip's issue 1668 [Default to --user](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668) and other issues linked therein.

Most common solutions are:

- Installing Python packages in user's home directory (*[user scheme](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)*)
- Compiling Python from source and using this instance instead of the system one

Theoretically another possible solution would be using `--target` option with pip and setting `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. However `--target` option has many (currently 12) [problems](https://github.com/pypa/pip/labels/--target%20option).